# Nuxtjs error render function or template not defined in component: carousel

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have installed vue carousel via npm

```
  "dependencies": {
   "nuxt": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-carousel": "^0.6.9"
  },
```

Now in my nuxt configurations

```
  plugins: [
  '~/plugins/vue-carousel'
 ],
```

And the vue-carousel.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueCarousel from 'vue-carousel';

 Vue.use(VueCarousel);
```

Now in my components am using it as

```
<template>
   <div>
        <carousel>
        <slide>
             Slide 1 Content
        </slide>
        <slide>
            Slide 2 Content
         </slide>
       </carousel>
   </div>
  </template>
 <script>

   import Carousel from 'vue-carousel';
   import Slide from 'vue-carousel';
   export default {
      components:{
         Carousel,Slide
      }

    }
```

Where am i going wrong as am getting an error

```
render function or template not defined in component: carousel
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nuxt has a different way to **configure** and **include** packages like `vue-carousel` in the project

**Below are the steps**

- Install `vue-carousel` as local dependency

`npm install --save vue-carousel`

- In nuxt project, under `plugins` directory create a file `plugins/externalVueCarousel.js` and add `vue-carousel` as a global component ([reference link](https://ssense.github.io/vue-carousel/guide/))

`import Vue from 'vue'; import VueCarousel from 'vue-carousel'; Vue.use(VueCarousel);`

- In `nuxt.config.js` file , include below code under `plugins`

`plugins: [{ src: '~/plugins/externalVueCarousel.js', ssr: false }],`

- The project is now ready to use `vue-carousel` in pages or components. `vue-carousel` is configured with global scope.
- Under pages or components try the examples given in [vue-carousel official website](https://ssense.github.io/vue-carousel/examples/)

**Sample program**

Place below code under pages/components and validate the result in-case if you would like to test a program ASAP

```
<template>
  <div class="mycarousel">
    <carousel :perPage="1">
      <slide>
        <span class="label">Slide 1 Content</span>
      </slide>
      <slide>
        <span class="label">Slide 2 Content</span>
      </slide>
      <slide>
        <span class="label">Slide 3 Content</span>
      </slide>
    </carousel>
  </div>
</template>

<style>
  body{
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  .mycarousel{
    left: 50%; 
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  .VueCarousel{
    display:inline-block;
  }
  .VueCarousel-slide {
    position: relative;
    background: #42b983;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

**Referred from**  https://nuxtjs.org/examples/plugins/